# Get tcp socket sequence number an ack number

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Is there a way to know that is the current sequence number and ack number of an open tcp socket?

I know this can be done by sniffing all outgoing data. 
The question is, could it also be done using API?

Comment: @EJP constructing a packet with FIN flag to force a remote device to close a telnet connection to it.

Comment: Well TCP was carefully designed with random initial sequence numbers to prevent you doing things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The socket interface doesn't provide access to that information. The only two ways to get it are:

- packet capturing like you suggested
- implement your own TCP stack in userspace using raw sockets as the API to the kernel.

The second option is obviously a huge project! :-)

Comment: yep...defensively not gonna get stuck with a stack

Comment: Can implementing ioctl in network driver be third way?