# C code to get TCP sequence numbers for Windows, Linux and Mac

Tags: c, tcp, raw-sockets

Is there a way (using raw sockets or otherwise) to get the TCP sequence numbers used by a process. So for example if a process is active and has an active TCP connection, is it possible to get the TCP sequence numbers for that process from the time the process was started, or at least the last acknowledgement number it received or sent? If so how do I do that using C or any low level language?

In effect, can:

- ProcessA detect the TCP sequence numbers that have already been sent (by the time ProcessA has started) associated with an active ProcessB?

Or

- Can a ProcessA detect the last ACK number received or sent by ProcessA after the fact?

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code for wireshark. http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get tcp socket sequence number an ack number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141731/get-tcp-socket-sequence-number-an-ack-number)

Comment: Disagree as duplicate since wireshark can show these values

Comment: I think you would have to make Process B some sort of tunnel or proxy that Process A goes through to reach the outside world.

Comment: MartyE, tunnel won't help me because it can only capture the current packet stream. I was to find the sequence numbers after the fact. So example is "ProcessB begins. Creates a tcp connection. last ACk number is 3456. ProcessA begins. ProcessA attempts to figure out the ack 3456 that has already been sent."

Comment: There are probably other more efficient ways of doing that. `netstat -n -p` display an association of processes with its various TCP/IP connections and do that instantly, no need to listen to network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the options mentioned already, [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is the best as it offers you a close to platform-independent way of capturing packets.

However, another option on Linux and that I have grown fond of, is to use the iptables [NFQUEUE](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/using-nfqueue-and-libnetfilter_queue/) target to send the packets you are interested in to userspace (possibly in combination with tee). With this technique, you can use the powers of iptables to only get the packets that you are interested in (for example SYN or some random packets based on probability).

An example of how to use NFQUEUE is [here](http://gitorious.org/meshias/mainline/blobs/c2b49e10f3175e979724f5b6109454dc51e83e47/src/examples/nfqueue.c) and [here](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/using-nfqueue-and-libnetfilter_queue/). Use NFQUEUE in the raw table to make sure all packets are evaluated. [Libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) should be used to ease the process of receiving packets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use winpcap, http://www.winpcap.org/ to capture the TCP data packets.  It has an API where you get access to all packets going to and fro on your NIC.  You can access the full packet, so you can extract any information you like from the it.

But you have to be monitoring a connection to know the sequence number, of course.  You have to extract the sequence number from live packets.  If you decide to break into a already running connection, you have to wait for the next packet to get your info.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a packet analyzer to see the value of sequence number and acknowledgment number used by a process. wireshark is a well known packet analyzer which works in all platform.

if you wish to write your own packet analyzer you have to use the library winpcap for windows, pcap for linux.

Download and run this program.  [sniffex](http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c)

you will get much idea about monitoring and capturing packets.